# Problems with links not working on local server

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up my site in Dreamweaver CS5 to work with my local server, and I'm having issues with document relative links.

I've got a structure on my HD like this

```
website
    _Common
         header.php
    _css
        twoColFixRtHdr.css
    index.php
```

and the same structure mirrored on my local WAMP server, except on the local server the site is in a subfolder, so it's something like www/website/

The problem is this line inside header.php

```
<link href="../_css/twoColFixRtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

That looks correct to me pathwise, but on the local server it cannot find that css file from the header.php

If I change it to

```
<link href="/website/_css/twoColFixRtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link href="_css/twoColFixRtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It works fine, but I want to use document relative links if I can, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds clear to me, since I'm sure that you include the header file in the index.php file. So the path for the css files is set relatively to the index.php.

Comment: Ah ok I get it, what kept throwing me is DW kept putting "../" in front of things, so it looks like it doesn't take into account that it's going to be loaded in via the included header.php file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve it by several ways.
one of them: you can setup a VirtualHost (in httpd.conf) and point your subfolder as root folder for host.

Answer (score 0):

If `header.php` is being included in `index.php`, the relative link `../_css/` in `header.php` won't work because index.php is at the same level as `_css`.

For all intents and purposes, once it's been included in `index.php`, to the browser, the content in `header.php` *is* now simply part of `index.php`, so all paths need to be relative to `index.php`.

Ie:

index.php

/my_include_folder
 - header.php

/_css
 - style.css

Once I add `<?php include('my_include_folder/header.php); ?>` to index.php, the links to css files, js, and hyperlinks in `header.php` should be relative to `index.php`.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Ah ok I get it, what kept throwing me is DW kept putting "../" in front of things, so it looks like it doesn't take into account that it's going to be loaded in via the included header.php file. Thanks.